# error 'too many inputs arguments' with rowfun

Tags: matlab

Why doesn't this anonymous function work with `rowfun`?

```
>> T = table([43;52;67;28],[64;24;69;45])
>> rowfun(@(x) sum(x), T)

Error using tabular/rowfun>dfltErrHandler (line 497)
Applying the function '@(x)sum(x)' to the 1st row of A generated the following
error:

Too many input arguments.
```

Comment: Are you really sure that `rowfun(@sum, T)` is the result that you're intending to get?

Comment: @Sardar Usama, you're right, it isn't, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation that you want to perform here is [`plus`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plus.html), not [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) and there should be two inputs to the anonymous function i.e.

```
rowfun(@(x,y) plus(x,y), T)
```

which is also equivalent to:

```
rowfun(@plus, T)
```

Output:

```
ans =    
  4×1 table

    Var1
    ____

    107 
     76 
    136 
     73
```